# Learning roadmap in Algebra

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, field-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I am a senior undergraduate student in mathematics, I have a sound knowledge in the following areas:

a) Commutative Algebra

b) Field Theory and Galois Theory

c) Homological Algebra

My question is given that I have knowledge in the above topics which is the next field that is appropriate to pick up to continue my studies in Algebra.
This I feel is a relavent question because its always fun to pick up a field that is just out your reach and try to understand and master it, this is where I need help.

When you suggest a field keep in mind that it should just be out of reach in terms of abstractness, and please specify weather the suggested field actually applies the above topics or is a new topic in itself.

If possible post links to recommended book lists by famous mathematicians working in that field

For instance the book list for algebraic topology by Hatcher is a good example

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/topologybooks.pdf

Thank you

Comment: I can recommend reading Chapter I in Robin Hartshorne's algebraic geometry, where one is introduced to the classical language of algebraic varieties. A lot of the commutative algebra machinery was developed because of Algebraic Geometry. If you want to learn more algebraic geometry after this, I highly recommend Foundations of Algebraic Geometry by Ravi vakil, which can be read for free here :http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf

Comment: You can also start reading up on Algebraic Number theory, which is a nice follow up to Field Theory and Galois theory. You can take a look at Milne's notes here :http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf